# How to check if object is selected?

Tags: jquery

I have an objects defined in jQuery, and I have list, I need to make a function to check if one object from the list is selected. I am trying with this code but it won't work. Can someone help me? The .selectable is the list.

```
if ( $('.selectable').is(':selected') ) {
            $('#edit').click(function () {
                $('#high-level').hide();
                $('#low-level').show();
            })

        }
```

Comment: could you please tell what kind of element we're talking about, I think you are looking for `$("..").is(":focus")`

Comment: is it throwing an error or just dont returning any selected? what kind of element are you selecting?

Comment: it's an object from an array

Comment: Please, show the relevant HTML that you're talking about.

Comment: Please add html / fiddle.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3fZ3GaFU

Comment: Put it in the question, not a remote web site.

Comment: Just a little note. Actually you don't need the edit button at all. It is possible to show the data to edit with a click on the student name. Do you really need this button?

Comment: I need it because I need to change info about one student.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to:

```
$('.selectable').append("<li><span class='name'>" + data[i].name + " </span><span class='grade'>" + prosek + "</span></li>");
```

Comment this line (this is not a function) and will give an error:

```
//$('.selectable').selectable();
```

Change your function like this:

```
$('.selectable li').on('click', function(){
                console.log($(this).find('.name').html());
                    var name = $(this).find('.name').html();
                    var grade = $(this).find('.grade').html();
                    $("#name").val(name)
                    $("#index").val(grade)
                    $('#high-level').hide();
                    $('#low-level').show();

            })
```

Now just click on the student name to load the student data into the inputs. Actually you don't need an extra button to do this.

**NOTE:** I advise you to do it in this way because your target is to retrieve the student names.

Additional info to your new comment:

This is the list:

[image]

And this is whe I click on one of them:

[image]

Here is the complete HTML page, maybe you have your javascript in the wrong place:

```
<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        input {
            width: 90px;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        li:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #feedback {
            font-size: 1.4em;
        }

        .selectable .ui-selecting {
            background: #FECA40;
        }

        .selectable .ui-selected {
            background: #F39814;
            color: white;
        }

        .selectable {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 40%;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .selectable li {
            margin: 3px;
            padding: 0.4em;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .content {
            width: 300px;
            background: #eef;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px grey dotted;
            font-size: 1.4em;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

<div id="high-level">
    <button id="edit">Edit students</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <ol class="selectable"></ol>
</div>

<div id="low-level">
    <div>
        <input id="prev" value="prev" type="button"/>
        <input id="top" value="top" type="button"/>
        <input id="next" value="next" type="button"/>
    </div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input id="name" class="content"></input><br/>
    <label>Index</label>
    <input id="index" class="content"></input>

    <div id="grades" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
    <button id="save">Save</button>
</div>





    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [
            {
                index: 123123,
                name: "Nikola Nikolovski",
                grades: [
                    {
                        course: "Calculus",
                        grade: 10
                    },
                    {
                        course: "OOP",
                        grade: 9
                    },
                    {
                        course: "Interactive Applications",
                        grade: 10
                    },
                ],
                edit: false
            },
            {
                index: 123124,
                name: "Petko Petkovski",
                grades: [
                    {
                        course: "User Interfaces",
                        grade: 8
                    },
                    {
                        course: "OOP",
                        grade: 9
                    },
                    {
                        course: "Interactive applications",
                        grade: 8
                    },
                ],
                edit: false
            },
            {
                index: 123125,
                name: "Petar Petrevski",
                grades: [
                    {
                        course: "Calculus",
                        grade: 6
                    },
                    {
                        course: "OOP",
                        grade: 9
                    },
                    {
                        course: "User Interfaces",
                        grade: 10
                    },
                ],
                edit: false
            }

        ];

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#high-level').show();
            $('#low-level').hide();

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

               var sum = 0;
               var prosek = 0;

               for (var j = 0; j < data[i].grades.length; j++) {
                   sum += data[i].grades[j].grade;
               }

               prosek = sum / data[i].grades.length;
               prosek = prosek.toFixed(2);


               $('.selectable').append("<li><span class='name'>" + data[i].name + " </span><span class='grade'>" + prosek + "</span></li>");
            }



            var $selected = $('.selectable .ui-selected').val();

            console.log($selected)

             $('.selectable li').on('click', function(){
                console.log($(this).find('.name').html());
                    var name = $(this).find('.name').html();
                    var grade = $(this).find('.grade').html();
                    $("#name").val(name)
                    $("#index").val(grade)
                    $('#high-level').hide();
                    $('#low-level').show();

            })



            $('#top').click(function () {
                $('#high-level').show();
                $('#low-level').hide();
            });

        })

    </script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: If i comment that line, I won't be able to see the list. So how can I show the list?

Comment: That's strange on my localhost is working as aspected  I will look at it. I have just used your code as it is. Give me 5 min.

Comment: I have just added the results from my localhost. Maybe you have commented the line not properly. Try to remove the line, and don't forget to reload the browser.

Comment: I have tried, and still it doesn't work. Would u mind sending me your code to try it?

Comment: If I don't use selectable I wouldn't need the edit button, so that's not the point. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Did you try the file  I have posted for you? You don't say anything about it so I am wondering.

Comment: yes I tried and it helped me, I removed the edit button hahah ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array, testing whether each element is selected. The code below assumes `list` is an array of element IDs.

```
var is_selected = false;
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if ($("#" + list[i]).is(":selected")) {
        is_selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please have a look at this? I have removed this line '$('.selectable').selectable();' because I think is not oing anything useful. Addictionally I get the error 'selectable is not a function'. She say now that she can not display the list. As you can see from the snapshots everything is working correctly. What do you think?  Cheers :)

Comment: If you're getting that error, it means you haven't loaded the jQuery UI Selectable plugin.

Comment: If you're not using that plugin, it doesn't make sense for a `<li>` to be selected, you can only select options from a `<select>` menu.